# converting iterrows into Vectorized operations in Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, performance

I have two data frames, lets just say donor_df and receiver_df
both have same indexes and columns
columns = [group, channel, wg, site, hc]
indexes = [group, channel, wg]
and have a donating_hc which denotes donating_hc should be reduced from donor_df equal and should be added to corresponding columns of receiver_df for given donor_group, donor_channel to receiver_group, receiver_channel
example:

```
donor_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  A    C1       wg1 site1 10 
#                wg2 site2 10
#                wg3 site3 10


receiver_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  B    C1       wg1 site1 10 
#                wg2 site2 10
#                wg3 site3 10

donating_hc = 10 
donor_group = A, donor_channel = C1
and reciever_group = B receiver_channel = C1

then donating_hc should be reduced equal from donor df group A and channel C1 and should be added to reciever hc group b and channel C1

result


donor_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  A    C1       wg1 site1 6.6667 
#                wg2 site2 6.6667
#                wg3 site3 6.6667


receiver_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  B    C1       wg1 site1 13.3333
#                wg2 site2 13.3333
#                wg3 site3 13.3333

and also if wg and site is not present it should be added at the end
example


donor_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  A    C1       wg1 site1 10 
#                wg2 site2 10
#                wg3 site4 10


receiver_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  B    C1       wg1 site1 10 
#                wg2 site2 10
#                wg3 site3 10

result should be
           

donor_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  A    C1       wg1 site1 6.6667 
#                wg2 site2 6.6667
#                wg3 site3 6.6667


receiver_df

#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  B    C1       wg1 site1 13.3333
#                wg2 site2 13.3333
#                wg3 site3 10
#                wg3 site4 13.3333
```

i tried a solution with loops i want a optimised solution with vectorisation
dataframes should be changed in place

Comment: Hi Sai! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify how the calculation works. Why does it change by 3.3333? explain it like I'm 5

Comment: Hi Mark, I wanted to give HC from given Group, channel of  donor df to given Group channel of receiver df and that is denoted by donating_hc.
andalso wanted to do distribute it in equal manner from all WG and sites 
in above example donating_hc is 10 and donor_df as follows
#                    site  hc 
# group channel  wg  
#  A    C1       wg1 site1 10 
#                wg2 site2 10
#                wg3 site4 10
for wg1, site hc to be donated is  donating_hc * hc / total_hc
here hc represents hc of wg1, site and total_hc represents total hc of wg1, wg2, wg3
ie 10 * 10/30 = 3.333

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

donor_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(',group,channel,wg,site,hc\n0,A,C1,wg1,site1,10\n1,A,C1,wg2,site2,10\n2,A,C1,wg3,site3,10\n')).drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
receiver_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(',group,channel,wg,site,hc\n0,B,C1,wg1,site1,10\n1,B,C1,wg2,site2,10\n2,B,C1,wg3,site3,10\n')).drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])

donating_hc = 10
donor_group = "A"
donor_channel = "C1"
receiver_group = "B"
receiver_channel = "C1"

donor_df['hc'] = donor_df.groupby(['group', 'channel'])['hc'].transform(lambda x: x - (donating_hc / len(x)) if (x.name[0] == donor_group and x.name[1] == donor_channel) else x)
receiver_df['hc'] = receiver_df.groupby(['group', 'channel'])['hc'].transform(lambda x: x + (donating_hc / len(x)) if (x.name[0] == receiver_group and x.name[1] == receiver_channel) else x)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the Answer
can we change it a bit so that same site HC from donor should be add to receiver and if the site is not present in receiver then we should new site row in receiver.
Example:
if site1 is reduced by 3.3333 from donor then same should be a added to site1 in receiver